# Is it necessary to build another project to fit mobile devices when using reactjs plus redux?

Tags: cordova, mobile, reactjs, react-native

As a simple project, we built the website using reactjs+redux. But now, business grows, we need to build the native apps to fit mobile devices, not only the mobile browser.

I did some read work about React Native, it seems not possible to use current JS code directly to build native apps for mobile.

Some of my colleague suggested to build another project for the mobile. But I'm wandering, how could the JS technique show its power to do fast iteration if I have to build another project just to do the same thing on the mobile.

I know Cordova and did some work on it, but not very much.

So, is there some guideline of integrating current JS code to Cordova?

or is there any suggestion? 
Thanks.

Comment: Does the website already have a mobile / responsive implementation?

Comment: @NaderDabit Used some frameworks maybe not not compatible with the mobile/responsive. and not compatible with mobile browsers. So, if modify the original code directly, is it going to lose the performance priority? Or increasing the complexity? How do we select between two solutions on the common sense?

Comment: To be honest I have not had a great experience rendering web views into an app. It would probably be best to create your app with a native language. It is possible to do what you are asking, but there are annoying things about it that I have not liked

Comment: Alright then. Thanks for replying....